# HQL: query only base table from <join> entity

Tags: nhibernate, join

I have this mapping

```
<class name="Person" table="person">
<id name="Id" column="id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>

<property name="Code" column="code" type="String" not-null="true" />
<property name="FirstName" column="firstName" type="String" not-null="true" />
<property name="MiddleName" column="middleName" type="String" not-null="false" />
<property name="LastName" column="lastName" type="String" not-null="false" />

<join table="personPhoto" optional="true">
  <key column="personId" />
  <property name="Photo" column="pictureContent" not-null="false" />
</join>
```

and the generated SQL always use left outer join, which is correct.
However, is it possible to tell HQL to query only from person table, since I'm not always need 'Photo' property? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a one-to-one relationship between person and personPhoto columns?

If you want to load the person's photo lazily, I believe you have to change join mapping to one-to-one mapping and create a new class for personPhoto. This way Hibernate would be able to insert a proxy object.

Comment: Yes it has one-to-one relation in database. Unfortunately I can't add a new class personPhoto.

Comment: I am afraid you are out of luck then. Hibernate needs a class to base the lazy loading proxy on.

Comment: This is so frustrating, no other way or workarounds? since It's not possible to change the database and I don't have access to add new domain object. Any idea? anyone?